# SAS- use proc arbor to bin variables

Tags: sas, decision-tree, bins

I'm trying to use PROC ARBOR to define bins for a continuous variable. The generated tree works well, and I can find the bin limits by visual exploration, but I would like to extract those bins and use them to discretize the original variable in an automatic way. Is this possible?

My code is:

```
%macro INTINPUTS;
    l_G_MERGE6_t1_monto6
%mend INTINPUTS;
proc arbor data=labo2.J_TABLA_MODELO_LOGS
Leafsize=5 Mincatsize = 5 Maxbranch=2 Maxdepth=6 alpha = 0.2
Padjust= CHAIDBEFORE DEPTH MAXRULES=1 MAXSURRS=0 Missing=USEINSEARCH Exhaustive=5000 ;
input %INTINPUTS
/ level = interval;
target A_C_0804_flag_compro / level=INTERVAL
Criterion=PROBF;;
Performance DISK
NodeSize=20000;
Assess NoValidata measure=ASE;
SUBTREE BEST ;
MAKEMACRO NLEAVES=nleaves;
save

NODESTAT=work.Tree_OUTNODES
SUMMARY=work.Tree_OUTSUMMARY

code file="C:\labo2\EMPUBLISHSCORE.sas"
group=Tree;
code file="C:\labo2\EMFLOWSCORE.sas"
group=Tree
residual;
run;
quit;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*In the discussion below I have been unable to check any code as I do not currently have access to Enterprise Miner.*

There are several ways to get at the information you want. Although, as they are intended for use by EM rather than humans they are can seem little obfuscated.

You can ask the procedure to output its set of rules using the `save rules = <dataset>;` statement. This will create a dataset with all of the splitting rules. The format is a bit odd, but the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/miner/em43/allproc.pdf) explains how it should be interpreted.

You can use the code generated to bin your data. The code file written by the `code file = <fileref>;` can be dropped into a data step where data of the correct structure is read in. Something like this:

```
data out; 
    set in; 
    %include <fileref>; 
run;
```

An example of the same concept (albeit for `proc split` rather than `proc arboretum`) can be seen [here](http://statcompute.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/a-sas-macro-for-bootstrap-aggregating-bagging/).

You can use the `score data = <inDataset> out = <outDataset>;` statement to have the procedure apply the tree to your data set. This can be combined with the `save model = <dataset>;` statement to allow for later use of the same model via the `inmodel = <dataset>` option. This would look something like:

```
/* Training */
proc arboretum data = histDS;
    /*...*/
    save model = modelDef;
    score data = histDS out = histTree;
run;

/* Scoring */

proc arboretum inmodel = modelDef;
    score data = newDS out = newTree;
run;
```

An example of how some of the `save` output datasets can be used is available [here](http://www.sasanalysis.com/2011/02/visualize-decision-tree-by-coding-proc.html).